# How do I disable the text replacement of "the WHO" with "The Who" and "doctor who" with "Doctor Who"? (Easter egg? Auto-incorrect.)

Tags: accessibility, macos

I guess it's supposed to be a pair of cute Easter eggs, but I'm sick of them.

How do I disable the text replacement of "the WHO" with "The Who"?

[image: bug screenshot]

<s><sup>How do I disable the text replacement of "doctor who" with "Doctor Who"?</sup></s> <sup>(Struck because strangely, this half of the Easter egg seems to have disappeared.  But now I'm noticing that it's capitalizing the *easter* in Easter egg for me. Which I don’t mind.)</sup>

They're not set up under my "Text Replacement" settings, AKA "Symbol and Text Substitution" System Preferences...

I think it's an Easter egg in Big Sur.  I'm seeing it here in Safari, and in Notes, both on Big Sur.  I'm not seeing it in those or the SE app on iOS.

Comment: Good to know that it somehow solved itself on your device. I've linked it to a similar question where the answer might help people.

Comment: FWIW Testing in **macOS Big Sur** 11.6, with default **macOS** settings, then in **Notes** if I typed **the who** it did the popup as you described **The Who**, to which I pressed the **esc** _key_.  I then went to **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Text**  and unchecked **[] Capitalize words automatically**. It then no longer presented **The Who** when typing *the who**. Not sure I would say that was an acceptable workaround, however, if it bothers you that much then you can do this until there is another way.

Comment: Why did you make my question less informative by removing half the examples? Different app and before vs after.

And were there a bunch of comments that are now gone?

Strange to have this question marked as a duplicate of one asked long after I asked this one, but I guess that's a limitation; it does have more informative/detailed answers.

Comment: (I thought I commented over there too, pointing folks here.)

Comment: When closing as duplicate we keep the question with the best answers open. This isn‘t always the older question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait.  All of these glitches, which I'm going to name **Halloween eggs**, at least for now, are no longer occurring on my iPhone XR, which is 1 minor release behind.  Only the **E**aster eggs one is now occurring (on my M1 MacBook with Monterey).